# How to populate dependable values into dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to make a car year, make, model dependable values form. My arrays are in the following format. For the selected year and selected make, i want to populate the corresponding model value.
I have put unique year and make into separate another array. How will i achieve the intended result?

```
    var car_arrays = [
  {
    id: 1,
    year: 1909,
    make: "Ford",
    model: "Model T",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    year: 1926,
    make: "Chrysler",
    model: "Imperial",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    year: 1948,
    make: "Citroën",
    model: "2CV",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    year: 1950,
    make: "Hillman",
    model: "Minx Magnificent",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    year: 1953,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    year: 1954,
    make: "Cadillac",
    model: "Fleetwood",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    year: 1954,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    year: 1955,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    year: 1955,
    make: "Ford",
    model: "Thunderbird",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    year: 1956,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    year: 1957,
    make: "BMW",
    model: "600",
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    year: 1957,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    year: 1958,
    make: "BMW",
    model: "600",
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    year: 1958,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    year: 1958,
    make: "Ford",
    model: "Thunderbird",
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    year: 1959,
    make: "Austin",
    model: "Mini",
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    year: 1959,
    make: "BMW",
    model: "600",
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    year: 1959,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    year: 1960,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvair",
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    year: 1960,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    year: 1960,
    make: "Fairthorpe",
    model: "Rockette",
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    year: 1960,
    make: "Fillmore",
    model: "Fillmore",
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    year: 1961,
    make: "Austin",
    model: "Mini Cooper",
  },
  {
    id: 26,
    year: 1961,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    year: 1961,
    make: "Pontiac",
    model: "Tempest",
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    year: 1961,
    make: "Studebaker",
    model: "Avanti",
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    year: 1962,
    make: "Buick",
    model: "Special",
  },
  {
    id: 28,
    year: 1962,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 27,
    year: 1962,
    make: "Pontiac",
    model: "Grand Prix",
  },
  {
    id: 29,
    year: 1962,
    make: "Studebaker",
    model: "Avanti",
  },
  {
    id: 31,
    year: 1963,
    make: "Austin",
    model: "Mini",
  },
  {
    id: 32,
    year: 1963,
    make: "Austin",
    model: "Mini Cooper S",
  },
  {
    id: 37,
    year: 1963,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvair 500",
  },
  {
    id: 38,
    year: 1963,
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Corvette",
  },
  {
    id: 34,
    year: 1963,
    make: "Ford",
    model: "E-Series",
  },
  {
    id: 36,
    year: 1963,
    make: "Pontiac",
    model: "Grand Prix",
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    year: 1963,
    make: "Rambler",
    model: "Classic",
  },];

function getYear() {
  var makeid = document.getElementById("makeid");
  var select, option;
  select = document.getElementById("yearid");
  for (let y in year) {
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = option.text = year[y];
    select.add(option);
  }
  var selectyear = document.getElementById("yearid");
  makeid.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
function getMake() {
  var makeid, yearid, option;
  makeidselect = document.getElementById("makeid");
  yearidselect = document.getElementById("yearid");

  for (let y in year) {
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = option.text = year[y];
    yearidselect.add(option);
    console.log(yearidselect.value);
  }
  for (let x in make) {
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = option.text = make[x];
    makeidselect.add(option);
    console.log(makeidselect.value);
  }
 var year = [
  1909, 1926, 1948, 1950, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961,
  1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974,
  1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987,
  1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000,
  2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013,
  2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021,
];
var make = [
  "Ford",
  "Chrysler",
  "Citroën",
  "Hillman",
  "Chevrolet",
  "Cadillac",
  "BMW",
  "Austin",
  "Fairthorpe",
  "Fillmore",
  "Pontiac",
  "Studebaker",
  "Buick",
  "Rambler",
  "Plymouth",
  "Volkswagen",
  "Jensen",
  "Oldsmobile",
  "Mercury",
  "Dodge",
  "Shelby",
  "Porsche",
  "Toyota",
  "Mercedes-Benz",
  "MG",
  "Nissan",
  "Honda",
  "Mazda",
  "Renault",
  "Audi",
  "Lincoln",
  "Lotus",
  "Maserati",
  "Mitsubishi",
  "Saab",
  "Subaru",
  "Suzuki",
  "Lamborghini",
  "Merkur",
  "Land Rover",
  "Acura",
  "Lexus",
  "Eagle",
  "Alfa Romeo",
  "Daihatsu",
  "Geo",
  "GMC",
  "Hyundai",
  "Infiniti",
  "Isuzu",
  "Jaguar",
  "Jeep",
  "Saturn",
  "Volvo",
  "HUMMER",
  "Kia",
  "Holden",
  "Corbin",
  "Daewoo",
  "MINI",
  "Maybach",
  "Scion",
  "Spyker",
  "Aston Martin",
  "Bentley",
  "Panoz",
  "Rolls-Royce",
  "Spyker Cars",
  "Ferrari",
  "Hummer",
  "Morgan",
  "Peugeot",
  "Foose",
  "Aptera",
  "Smart",
  "Bugatti",
  "Tesla",
  "Ram",
  "FIAT",
  "Fiat",
  "McLaren",
  "BYD",
  "McLaren Automotive",
  "Mobility Ventures LLC",
  "Pagani",
  "Roush Performance",
  "smart",
  "SRT",
  "Genesis",
  "Karma",
  "Koenigsegg",
  "RUF Automobile",
  "STI",
  "Polestar",
  "Kandi",
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to populate the models dropdown
according to the values of year and make:

```js
var CARS = [{
    id: 1,
    year: 1909,
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Model T',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    year: 1926,
    make: 'Chrysler',
    model: 'Imperial',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    year: 1948,
    make: 'Citroën',
    model: '2CV',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    year: 1950,
    make: 'Hillman',
    model: 'Minx Magnificent',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    year: 1953,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    year: 1954,
    make: 'Cadillac',
    model: 'Fleetwood',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    year: 1954,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    year: 1955,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    year: 1955,
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Thunderbird',
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    year: 1956,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    year: 1957,
    make: 'BMW',
    model: '600',
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    year: 1957,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    year: 1958,
    make: 'BMW',
    model: '600',
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    year: 1958,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    year: 1958,
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Thunderbird',
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    year: 1959,
    make: 'Austin',
    model: 'Mini',
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    year: 1959,
    make: 'BMW',
    model: '600',
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    year: 1959,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    year: 1960,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvair',
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    year: 1960,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    year: 1960,
    make: 'Fairthorpe',
    model: 'Rockette',
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    year: 1960,
    make: 'Fillmore',
    model: 'Fillmore',
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    year: 1961,
    make: 'Austin',
    model: 'Mini Cooper',
  },
  {
    id: 26,
    year: 1961,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    year: 1961,
    make: 'Pontiac',
    model: 'Tempest',
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    year: 1961,
    make: 'Studebaker',
    model: 'Avanti',
  },
  {
    id: 30,
    year: 1962,
    make: 'Buick',
    model: 'Special',
  },
  {
    id: 28,
    year: 1962,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 27,
    year: 1962,
    make: 'Pontiac',
    model: 'Grand Prix',
  },
  {
    id: 29,
    year: 1962,
    make: 'Studebaker',
    model: 'Avanti',
  },
  {
    id: 31,
    year: 1963,
    make: 'Austin',
    model: 'Mini',
  },
  {
    id: 32,
    year: 1963,
    make: 'Austin',
    model: 'Mini Cooper S',
  },
  {
    id: 37,
    year: 1963,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvair 500',
  },
  {
    id: 38,
    year: 1963,
    make: 'Chevrolet',
    model: 'Corvette',
  },
  {
    id: 34,
    year: 1963,
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'E-Series',
  },
  {
    id: 36,
    year: 1963,
    make: 'Pontiac',
    model: 'Grand Prix',
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    year: 1963,
    make: 'Rambler',
    model: 'Classic',
  },
]

const YEARS = [
  1909, 1926, 1948, 1950, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961,
  1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974,
  1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987,
  1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000,
  2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013,
  2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021,
]
const MAKES = [
  'Ford',
  'Chrysler',
  'Citroën',
  'Hillman',
  'Chevrolet',
  'Cadillac',
  'BMW',
  'Austin',
  'Fairthorpe',
  'Fillmore',
  'Pontiac',
  'Studebaker',
  'Buick',
  'Rambler',
  'Plymouth',
  'Volkswagen',
  'Jensen',
  'Oldsmobile',
  'Mercury',
  'Dodge',
  'Shelby',
  'Porsche',
  'Toyota',
  'Mercedes-Benz',
  'MG',
  'Nissan',
  'Honda',
  'Mazda',
  'Renault',
  'Audi',
  'Lincoln',
  'Lotus',
  'Maserati',
  'Mitsubishi',
  'Saab',
  'Subaru',
  'Suzuki',
  'Lamborghini',
  'Merkur',
  'Land Rover',
  'Acura',
  'Lexus',
  'Eagle',
  'Alfa Romeo',
  'Daihatsu',
  'Geo',
  'GMC',
  'Hyundai',
  'Infiniti',
  'Isuzu',
  'Jaguar',
  'Jeep',
  'Saturn',
  'Volvo',
  'HUMMER',
  'Kia',
  'Holden',
  'Corbin',
  'Daewoo',
  'MINI',
  'Maybach',
  'Scion',
  'Spyker',
  'Aston Martin',
  'Bentley',
  'Panoz',
  'Rolls-Royce',
  'Spyker Cars',
  'Ferrari',
  'Hummer',
  'Morgan',
  'Peugeot',
  'Foose',
  'Aptera',
  'Smart',
  'Bugatti',
  'Tesla',
  'Ram',
  'FIAT',
  'Fiat',
  'McLaren',
  'BYD',
  'McLaren Automotive',
  'Mobility Ventures LLC',
  'Pagani',
  'Roush Performance',
  'smart',
  'SRT',
  'Genesis',
  'Karma',
  'Koenigsegg',
  'RUF Automobile',
  'STI',
  'Polestar',
  'Kandi',
]

MAKES.sort()

const yearSelection = document.getElementById('year')
const makeSelection = document.getElementById('make')
const modelSelection = document.getElementById('model')
const displayedCars = document.getElementById('cars')

for (let year of YEARS) {
  const option = document.createElement('option')
  option.textContent = year
  option.value = year
  yearSelection.appendChild(option)
}

for (let make of MAKES) {
  const option = document.createElement('option')
  option.textContent = make
  option.value = make
  makeSelection.appendChild(option)
}

const models = []
for (let car of CARS) {
  const model = car.model
  if (models.findIndex(m => m == model) == -1) {
    const option = document.createElement('option')
    option.className = 'car-model'
    models.push(model)
    option.textContent = model
    option.value = model
    modelSelection.appendChild(option)
  }
}

const modelOptions = Object.values(document.querySelectorAll('.car-model'))

function populateModels() {
  const selectedYear = yearSelection.value
  const selectedMake = makeSelection.value
  const filtered = CARS.filter(
    car => car.year == selectedYear && car.make == selectedMake
  )

  for (let option of modelOptions) {
    if (filtered.find(v => v.model == option.value)) {
      option.hidden = false
    } else {
      option.hidden = true
    }
  }

  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    modelSelection.value = filtered[0].model
  } else {
    modelSelection.value = 'none'
  }
}

populateModels()
yearSelection.onchange = () => populateModels()
makeSelection.onchange = () => populateModels()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" type="image/x-icon" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <select name="" id="year"></select>
  <select name="" id="make"></select>
  <select name="" id="model">
    <option value="none" disabled hidden>No models found</option>
  </select>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the array:

```
let year = [], let make = [],  ....

car_arrays.forEach(car => {
year.push(car.year) 
make.push(car.make) ...
})
```